# Detect whether the user has disable push notification permission from APN

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I understand we can add code on iOS client side to detect whether the user has disabled push notification permission, my question it, is it possible to do it in only using APN?

I try the "Feedback Service" first, from Apple Programming Guide:

> The Apple Push Notification service includes a feedback service to
>   give you information about failed remote notifications. When a remote
>   notification cannot be delivered because the intended app does not
>   exist on the device, the feedback service adds that device’s token to
>   its list. Remote notifications that expire before being delivered are
>   not considered a failed delivery and don’t impact the feedback
>   service. By using this information to stop sending remote
>   notifications that will fail to be delivered, you reduce unnecessary
>   message overhead and improve overall system performance.

[FeedBack Service payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AswBc.png)

So "Feedback Service" essentially give us a token list for failed push notifications. I tried to send push to a device with disabled push notification permission or app uninstalled , however my device token does not appear in this list.

Apple's document also mentions we will get immediate response from APN once we send the push notification:

> If you send a notification that is accepted by APNs, nothing is
>   returned. If you send a notification that is malformed or otherwise
>   unintelligible, APNs returns an error-response packet and closes the
>   connection. Any notifications that you sent after the malformed
>   notification using the same connection are discarded, and must be
>   resent. Figure A-2 shows the format of the error-response packet.

However, it seems like the returned status stays the same no matter what I do: enable/disable push notification permission or even uninstall the app...

I fact, my hypothesis is that even the user has disabled the push notification, APN will still see it as a successful delivery, but iOS just simply don't show it.  None of them response code from APN seem to be related to the disabled push notification.

I am wondering if there is a way to do it with APN? Thank you!

Reference: Apple Doc:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW1

Comment: I'm wondering too. I'm also interesting on how many time/how long will a token will appear in FeedBack if we're still sending it nofication.

Comment: I managed to obtain a Unregistered response from http2 after uninstalling an app, but I'm not sure it actually track device for (legacy) app that have been deleted long time ago. I did not manage to get something else that 200 for disabled push notification. Is there some delay here ?